# How can Unity connect with Secure WebSocket based on Node.js?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ssl, websocket, https

I created an `HTTPS` web server using `Node.js` and a socket server using `WebSocket`.

Both servers use the same `443` port.

For the web client, I was able to connect to the websocket server normally through the code below.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost/');
ws.onopen = () => {
  console.info(`WebSocket server and client connection`);

  ws.send('Data');
};
```

However, the websocket client code in `Unity` as shown below causes an error.

```
using WebSocketSharp;

...
private WebSocket _ws;

void Start()
{
  _ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost/");
  _ws.Connect();
  _ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
  {
    Debug.Log($"Received {e.Data} from server");
    Debug.Log($"Sender: {((WebSocket)sender).Url}");
  };
}

void Update()
{
  if(_ws == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
  {
    _ws.Send("Hello");
  }
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: The current state of the connection is not Open.

Is the Unity client unable to connect by inserting a `Self-Signed Certificate (SSC)` to configure `HTTPS`?

If you change to `HTTP` and set the port number to `80`, it's confirmed that the Unity client is also connected normally.

If it's an `SSL` issue, how do I fix the code to enable communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to the above issue.

The code below performs the process of connecting to the `WebSocket` server inside the web server from the `Unity client`.

**client.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;

public class client : MonoBehaviour
{
     private WebSocket _ws;
     
     private void Start()
     {
          _ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost/");
          _ws.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
          
          Debug.Log("Initial State : " + _ws.ReadyState);

          _ws.Connect();
          _ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
          {
               Debug.Log($"Received {e.Data} from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + "");
          };
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if(_ws == null) 
         {
              return;
         }

         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {
              _ws.Send("Unity data");
         }
     }
}
```